# Show $\dfrac{(n!)^{a}n^{bn}}{\left( (2n)!\right)^{c}}\sim Kn^{(a+b-2c)n}n^{\frac{a-c}{2}}\left(e^{2c-a}2^{-2c} \right)^{n}$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show:
>   $$\dfrac{(n!)^{a}n^{bn}}{\left( (2n)!\right)^{c}}\sim Kn^{(a+b-2c)n}n^{\frac{a-c}{2}}\left(e^{2c-a}2^{-2c} \right)^{n} \mbox{ with } k=2^{\frac{a}{2}-c}\pi^{\frac{a-c}{2}}$$

**My proof:**

note that :

> $$n!\sim \left( \dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(n!)^{a}n^{bn}}{\left( (2n)!\right)^{c}}&\sim \dfrac{\left(\left( \dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\right)^{a}n^{bn}}{ \left(\left( \dfrac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\sqrt{2\pi 2n}\right)^{c}} \\
&\sim \dfrac{n^{a+b-2c}}{(4e)^{n}}n^{n\left(\dfrac{a}{2}-c \right)}(2\pi)^{n\left(\frac{a}{2}-c \right)}\dfrac{1}{(4e)^{n}} \\ 
\end{align*}

- I can't get what they annonced

Comment: first thing I notice is the lack of $\mathrm{e}^{2nc}$ so I suggest going over your calculation again being careful this time.

Comment: For this kind of problems, take logarithms and use Stirling for $\log(n!)$. It works fine here.

Comment: i tried what you said both but i can't manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\dfrac{(n!)^{a}n^{bn}}{\left( (2n)!\right)^{c}}\sim \dfrac{\left(\left( \dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\right)^{a}n^{bn}}{ \left(\left( \dfrac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\sqrt{2\pi 2n}\right)^{c}}
$$
so we have
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{an}}{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2nc}}\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi n)^a}{(2\pi 2n)^c}}n^{bn}=n^{(a-2c)n}\mathrm{e}^{(2c-a)n}2^{-2nc}\sqrt{(2\pi)^{a-c}}\sqrt{n^{a-c}}\sqrt{2^{-c}}n^{bn}
$$
this leads to
$$
\sqrt{(2\pi)^{a-c}}\sqrt{2^{-c}}=\pi^{\frac{a-c}{2}}2^{\frac{a}{2}-c}\\
n^{(a-2c)n}n^{bn} = n^{(b+a-2c)n}\\
\mathrm{e}^{(2c-a)n}2^{-2nc} = \left(\mathrm{e}^{2c-a}2^{-2c}\right)^n
$$

Give more steps of what you have tried and compare with above.